# Installing Windows 7 on secondary drive

Tags: windows, installation, ssd

I just installed an SSD in my laptop, it is the second drive. I boot from the first one.

Is there anyway I can install Windows 7 on the second drive while I it is also installed on the first? Or there is no other way and do I have to take out the first and put the second drive there then install Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's best to take out the first drive and install windows on the second drive. this will allow your new installation to not see the original one. Also when writing the boot files, you'll have overwritten your original installation's system reserved area. What this will do for you is allow you to pull up your boot menu (from the bios) and select which hard drive you wish to boot from. This, imo, is the preferred way to do such a thing in case you're looking to revert back or format the second drive. This way you have not affected your primary drive at all. Note. some computers have different key strokes for your bios boot menu.

Answer (score 3):

You can install it on the second drive without disconnecting the first, you just have to be careful to select the proper drive to install W7 on during setup.

Comment: This is very true. However, better safe than sorry IMO.

Comment: If you leave both connected during install it will add a nice bootloader so you can choose which OS to boot from when you start the PC.

Comment: Adding two win7 OSs on two drives was giving me an error for whatever reason :( so I went with the first answer above.

Answer (score 2):

When you boot from the windows 7 disc installation it will see both drives just choose your ssd drive to install it on there. You can only install one Os at a time you can have both going at once cause technically it's one computer if it's a separate computer sure why not.

hope that helps

Comment: "You can only install one Os at a time you can have both going at once cause technically it's one computer if it's a separate computer sure why not" makes absolutely no sense to me.  I'm so unsure of what you're trying to say that I don't even know if this deserves an up or downvote.

Comment: you have to hard drive drives installed on your laptop no? is it not consider as one computer? so how can you install 2 os at once?

Comment: There are plenty of laptops that support installing two simultaneous hard drives.  You can certainly install one OS on each.  Or you can install two OS on one hard drive.  There's no reason any of this is impossible...or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I think  there's a mis understanding what i'm try to imply you can have 2,3 or even 4 OS what i'm trying to tell you is that you can't install both at once. I understand you want 2 OS on your laptop i'm not suggesting that you can't do i'm just saying you can only setup one at a time. Once you're done installing on one drive you go the the next drive. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The confusion I think is caused by the typo in your answer.  You presumably mean "you *can't* have both going at once".

Comment: I think the confusion was that nobody was ever suggesting you install them SIMULTANEOUSLY.  Of course you do so one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect your first hdd the one you are using now. Now connect your second hdd and install you other version of windows onto it.
When it is all done connect up your original hdd & restart (switch off the PC or press reset button).

Soon as the PC begins to start press F8 which will bring up a bios boot menu with each hdd listed. Just choose the one you want to boot into.
You may have to press a different button to F8 but my motherboard is an asus so that is what I press.

Once yo get into your PC open system Configuration from admin tools/ click on boot and put whichever system you want as your main boot first and set it as default. That way it will always start when you don't press F8. The windows 10 boot manager is horrible and if you use it and chose windows 7 to boot it will shut down the PC an restart in windows 7. It is so slow.