# Windows on secondary drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

As discussed under [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1245432/installing-windows-on-secondary-hard-disk) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/342912/installing-windows-7-on-secondary-drive) questions (amongs a lot of others) it is definitely possible to have two totally independent installations of a Linux distribution and Windows next to eachother. Independent meaning that no grub or bootloader is involved, "multi-booting" is achieved through selecting a boot-drive from the BIOS.

As I haven't been a Windows user lately a question remains for me: will the Linux drive show up in Windows 10 as "not formatted" drive, and will I be prompted through Windows Explorer (e.g., by trying to open the "raw drive") to format it?

Other point of view: is it possible not to even show the drive in Windows Explorer? (In Control Panel / Computer Management, or whatever it is called nowadays, it will show, and one can screw up, that's no problem, I just don't want to have an easy way for my nephew to destroy my Linux drive with a couple of clicks in Windows Explorer.)

Comment: "will Drive I show up in Windows 10 as "not formatted" drive" - Yes, so install the appropriate file system drive to avoid that from happening.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: I have multiple dual boot systems. In all of them the Linux partitions appears as raw (in Windows) but it never asks to format.

Comment: @MichaelBay: if you double-click onto the "raw drive" in Explorer, what happens? Aren't you prompted to format the drive?

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried my best to reformat the question.

Comment: They don't appears in Explorer, for starters. You would need to open disk management.

Comment: @MichaelBay: exactly, that's the crucial point of my question. "is it possible not to even show the drive in Windows Explorer?" -> you say that it is by default not showing up. That's good news for me! Could you elaborate your comments as an answer please, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows you to hide a drive from explorer but not disk management to do this, go to computer management, disk management then right click the drive and select "change drive letter and paths".  In the next window that pops up you should see the drive letter highlighted.  Click on remove and OK.  The disk should now be hidden from explorer.

**edited**
as @MichaelBay stated though, no drive letter will be assigned so no drive letter to begin with.  The drive would only be visible from Computer Management.

Comment: Perhaps you should have read the comments first?? The drives DON'T show up by default, no drive letter assigned.

Comment: indeed, missed that.  I'll be sure to read comments next time!!

Comment: You can and should edit the answer accordingly. Fell free to use what I commented above.